# ::before is not working. What can be the problem

Tags: html, css

I want to put a Background image in a Container but the code is not working.

CSS   CODE

```
    .headerandmain::before {
        background-image: url(Images/HomeImg2.jpg);
    }
```

HTML CODE

```
<section class="headerandmain">

        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul class="navlink">
                    <li class="navabout">
                        <a href="#">
                            About
                        </a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="navhome"><a href="#">
                        Home
                    </a>

                    </li>


                    <li class="navdownload">
                        <a href="#">Download</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="navcontact">
                        <a href="#">
                                Contact
                            </a>

                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </section>
```

:: before is not working but Background-image(url) is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the beolw properties.

- content
- height
- width
- position
- z-index

```css
.headerandmain:before {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg");
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="headerandmain">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="navlink">
        <li class="navabout">
          <a href="#">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navhome"><a href="#">
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navdownload">
          <a href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navcontact">
          <a href="#">
            Contact
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `::before`?

if you need to set the background image of `::before`, I think you have to like this.

```
.headerandmain::before {
   content: '';
   width: xx; // set you want width..
   height: xx; // set you want height..
   position: xx; // set you want position..
   ... // need more some setting.
   background-image: url(Images/HomeImg2.jpg);
}
```

What container background image do you need to change?

Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I need :: before because I have to flip the picture. And In background-image, It flips whole element

Answer (score 0):

You most add  `content:''`  in  `.headerandmain::before`